# Trouble going on to the next page

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run my function to get some links from a certain site, it fetches the links from the first page but instead of going on to the next page to do the same, it breaks showing the following error.

Crawler:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Startpoint(mpage):
    page=4
    while page<=mpage:
        address = "https://www.katalystbusiness.co.nz/business-profiles/bindex"+str(page)+".html"
        tail="https://www.katalystbusiness.co.nz/business-profiles/"
        page = requests.get(address)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//p/a/@href')
        for title in titles:
            if "bindex" not in title:
                if "cdn-cgi" not in title:
                    print(tail + title)


    page+=1

Startpoint(5)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\New.py", line 19, in <module>
    Startpoint(5)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\New.py", line 6, in Startpoint
    while page<=mpage:
TypeError: unorderable types: Response() <= int()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the result of `requests.get(address)` to `page`. Then Python cannot compare a `requests.Response` object to an int. Simply call `page` something else like `response`. You also had an indentation error on your last line.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Startpoint(mpage):
    page=4
    while page<=mpage:
        address = "https://www.katalystbusiness.co.nz/business-profiles/bindex"+str(page)+".html"
        tail="https://www.katalystbusiness.co.nz/business-profiles/"
        response = requests.get(address)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//p/a/@href')
        for title in titles:
            if "bindex" not in title:
                if "cdn-cgi" not in title:
                    print(tail + title)


        page+=1

Startpoint(5)
```

Comment: Thanks sir bernie for your sharp response. It works like magic. Gonna accept your answer when this site allows me to do so. Thanks again.

Comment: What a legendary mistake I made but my head was spinning while finding that out. That's why coding should not be practiced on the fly. Thanks again sir, bernie.

Comment: It's quite alright. We all make mistakes. That's what SO is for :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `page` variable on the line: `page = requests.get(address)`

So, when it gets back to the `while page<=mpage:` on the second iteration, it's trying to compare `page` (which is now a response object) to `mpage` (an integer.)

Also, the `page+=1` should be inside the `while` loop.